# Android Java ViewStub for Empty Listview Adapter

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I am trying to get the empty.xml layout display when the adapter listview is empty.
I tried with http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/ 
But I can't do it.

**empty.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Principal"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_items"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:divider="#ebebeb"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    >
</ListView>

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/stub_import"
    android:layout="@layout/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Principal"
>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_items"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:divider="#ebebeb"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    >
</ListView>

<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/stub_import"
    android:layout="@layout/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I know the command to inflate and deflate is something.

```
   ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_import)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   // or
   View importPanel = ((ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stub_import)).inflate();
```

Where should I put the command to inflate when my listview is empty?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You usually don't use ViewStubs any more because we have fragments now. Consider reading something more up to date. The code would go whereever you need to empty view.

Comment: So can I do the same thing with Fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i do these in either of `onCreate` or `onResume`, by first checking if my listview is empty using the listview's **adapter.getCount()** method to check if the adapter is empty , then i inflate the **viewStub**.

My code looks like this :

```
if(adapter.getCount()==0){
        ViewStub stub=(ViewStub) viewRoot.findViewById(R.id.viewstub);
        stub.inflate();
    }
```

My XML file looks Like

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.younickacademy.younickmobile.Fragment_AlertsList"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

         <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_alerts"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
         <ViewStub
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout="@layout/empty_alert_list"
            android:id="@+id/viewstub"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_new_alert"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        android:background="@drawable/circular_button_selector"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And My **empty_alert_list.xml** layout looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="No Emergency Alerts have been received Yet."
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However this may not be the best implementation, but does solve my problem momentarily until  a better hack is found.